Performance Gap Between Validation and Test Sets (ResNet-18, k-Fold CV)
I'm working on a binary image classifier (ResNet-18) using k-fold cross-validation. During training,  the model's highest validation accuracy reached 99%. However, on a separate test set, the accuracy drops to 92%. I also observed a similar trend with the loss function, where the validation loss was lower compared to the test set loss.The label distribution in both the training and test data is balanced.
Why is there such a significant difference in performance between the validation and test sets?
